# how to update James‘s netty version to 4.xx?

Tags: java, netty, james

the james project still use old netty version 3.xxx, how  to update it to 4.xxx?
https://github.com/apache/james-project

in the file pom.xml, has defines the netty version  `<netty.version>3.10.6.Final</netty.version>`
when i change this  to

4.1.42.Final

,there is a lot of compile error on much java source file,
i think its to hard to update netty version, does someone  try do it?

Comment: hmm. Did you try to see what are the changes between 3.xxx and 4.xxx?

Comment: yeah, in the version 3 package are use jboss.xx ,  and in version 4,are  io.netty.xx
and version has upstream and downstream method,in version 4 instead channelRead

Comment: you might need to replace/rewrite certain code to compatible with version 4.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code needs to be updated to migrate to netty 4.1. As this is major version bump it is not backward compatible. Check https://netty.io/wiki/new-and-noteworthy-in-4.0.html for more details